# How does Potential Duplicate Component and Duplicate Record Sets work?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, data, duplicate-management, sales-cloud

***TLDR: Can we retrieve duplicate records in 'View Duplicates' using Apex or SOQL.***

[image]

***Details***

I am planning to create a list view with a column of 'View Duplicates' link or button. Similar to below image from Account record page.

**Is it possible to do so with Standard list view or I'll need to develop a Lightning Component?**
As per my knowledge List views don't support this, but anything that reduces custom developement is welcome.

For custom developement I've looked into the above **Potential Duplicate Component** which is standard lightning component and **Duplicate Record Sets** which stores Duplicate Record Items based on Duplicate rule.

But there seems to be no particular relation between these two. Below is a scenario-

I have a Duplicate Record Set with two Items.

[image]

But when I navigate to each Account from the list, View Duplicates is not available.

[image]
[image]

Moreover there are other Duplicate Record Sets with over 30+ records and most of their items don't have 'View Duplicates' option, and for those which do have only show 5 to 6 duplicates and not all within the Duplicate Record Sets.

- Does Potential Duplicate Component retrieve data from Duplicate Record Sets?
- What happens to existing Duplicate Record    Sets when a Duplicate
  Rule is changed?
- Can we create a link or button which would pop up the same window when 'View Duplicates' on record page is clicked?

Please let me know if I've missed out on any details.